# Javascript String to Date Conversion using new Date()

Tags: javascript, jquery, date, date-conversion

Please find my code below to convert date in string format to date format.

```
var olddatetxt = "10/01/2014"; //October 1st 2014
var olddatearray = olddate.split("/"); //Values inside array are [10,01,2014]
var olddate = new Date(olddatearray [2], olddatearray [0], olddatearray [1]);
```

The problem here is the variable olddate is getting the value as

```
Sat Nov 1 00:00:00 UTC+0530 2014
```

What is the error here ? Im passing values of October month & why my result is November 1st ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is the [Date](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date) takes month value as a 0 indexed value.

> month
>  Integer value representing the month, beginning with 0 for
>   January to 11 for December.

```js
var olddatetxt = "10/01/2014"; //October 1st 2014
var olddatearray = olddatetxt.split("/"); //Values inside array are [10,01,2014]
var olddate = new Date(olddatearray[2], olddatearray[0] - 1, olddatearray[1]);

document.querySelector('#result').innerHTML = olddate;
```

```html
<div id="result"></div>
```